# url formatting when processing a form

Tags: php, html, forms, url

So I have written this code for a form (search form) and it looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<select >
<option value="name">Client Name:</option>
<option value="email">Client Email:</option>
<option value="tnx_id">Transaction ID:</option>
<option value="amount">Amount:</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="svalue" placeholder="Search"></input>
<input type="image" name="submit" src="img/search_btn.png"></input>
</form>
```

When user clicks Search I want the url to be formatted this way:

```
http://localhost/pp/index.php?search&name=haha
```

But instead I get:

```
http://localhost/pp/index.php?search=name&svalue=haha&submit.x=0&submit.y=0
```

I'm only having difficulties formating the url correctly because the rest of the 
code is good, I cannot get rid of that `&submit.x=0&submit.y=0` at the end of the
url too. Do you have any ideas guys?
Basically my desired url format gets the selected option (name, email, tnx_id, amount)
and assigns svalue's value to it.

I'd  appreciated your help,
Thank you in advance,
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That is how forms work. Each control gives a name=value pair in the submitted data.

You could hack it with JavaScript, but that becomes fragile. Give the `<select>` element a name and change the server side script so that it takes the two pieces of data as separate pieces of data.

> I cannot get rid of that `&submit.x=0&submit.y=0` at the end of the url too

Remove the `name` attribute from the image map so it won't be a successful control.

```
<input type="image" src="img/search_btn.png">
```

---

Other improvements you should make:

- `<input>` is an empty element. It should not have an end tag. If you are writing XHTML then use the empty element syntax.
- `placeholder` should [not be used as a replacement for `<label>`](http://www.pardot.com/help/faqs/best-practices/placeholders-and-labels)
- Add an alt attribute to the image map

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I'm using it (name) because I'm styling the
submit button, this is the only way I do it.

Comment: Use `class` or `id` if you want to describe something just for styling purposes. `name` has no real purpose beyond saying what the key should be when submitting a form control.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to create the URL.  If you're using jQuery:

```
var url = 'http://localhost/pp/index.php?search&'
        + encodeURIComponent($('#id-of-your-select-element').val())
        + '='
        + encodeURIComponent($('#id-of-your-svalue-element').val());
```

**Edit:** As for getting rid of `submit.x` and `submit.y`, see @Quentin's answer.

Comment: That will fail if the user types in, for example, a `&`. Don't serialize arbitrary data into data formats without applying suitable escaping.

Comment: @Quentin: Of course you're correct, and I forgot.  It's still early. :-)  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your php code you can add this:-

```
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
$searchString="&cs=".$_GET['name'];
}
```

then use this:

```
http://localhost/pp/index.php?".$searchString."/
```

i think this will help you to get the right thing. if you want to use pagination with that,i have a code for you which i used before and it works great. just try it once!

Comment: Thank but I have the code that works with pagination. I simply modify the query based on the url format and it works good. You mean I should add 
action=".$searchString." at the beginning of the form?

Thanks.